# Discord.py: How Do I Embed Images From channel.history?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The server I made the bot for has an archive channel that stores images.

I wanted to create a bot that reads through the channel and resends the image based on the request. The code is as follows:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('!archive request'):
      channel = client.get_channel(714768885110538321)
      messages = await channel.history(oldest_first=True).flatten()

      request = ''
      for i in message.content.split():
        if i.isdigit():
          request += i

      await message.channel.send(messages[int(request)].content)
```

Basically, I want to resend an image that is posted to a specific channel. However, .content seems to result in an empty return. I tried using jump_url, and it sends the proper link, but it seems that discord can't embed images based on message links.

How would I be able to fix this? I would prefer to not store the images if possible.

Answer (score 2):

`channel.history` will return an asynchronous iterator so you need to use

```
async for ... in channel.history(...)
```

`message.content` won't return any attachments so you can check if the message has an attachment that is image by

```
if message.attachments[0].content_type.startswith("image"):
```

After you got the attachment, you can convert it into `discord.File` so you can send it using `send()`

```
image = message.attachments[0].to_file()
```

To wrap thing up:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!archive request'):
        channel = client.get_channel(714768885110538321)
        async for message in channel.history(oldest_first=True)
            if message.attachments[0].content_type.startswith("image"):
                image = message.attachments[0].to_file()
                await message.channel.send(file = image)
```